# Scala simple way to search timeStamps in a Map of timestamps

Tags: scala, search, collections

I have a

```
val timestampOffsetMap: Map[ZonedDateTime, Int]
```

would like to search nearest before timeStamp( a.k.a ZonedDateTime) to getOffset

```
def getNearestBeforeTimeStampOffset(timeToCheck: ZonedDateTime): Int = ???
```

I know about sortedMap and thinking about using it, but not sure if there is a better way to solve the problem.
Also I am on scala 2.11 for collections API

Comment: Can u post an example input and what should be the output, would help me to implement and test my code

Comment: Sure, Example:
Input:
ZonedDateTime.now()
Output:
28

Usage:

       `val offset = getNearestBeforeTimeStampOffset(ZonedDateTime.now)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

As Joe Pallas has pointed out, scala's default implementation of `TreeMap` provides essentially the same functionality as Java's `NavigableMap`. However, the API is quite different: on `TreeMap`, there are methods `from`, `to` and `range`, that create ranged projections of the `TreeMap`. On these ranged projections, the methods `headOption` and `tailOption` can be used to select elements that essentially correspond to `ceil` and `floor`-elements of a given key.

The reason why the API looks quite different (it returns entire trees instead of a single `ceil`/`floor`-elements), is that, somewhat counter-intuitively, building a ranged projection of an immutable tree is asymptotically just as expensive as retrieving a single element.

Nevertheless, I think that there is nothing wrong with using a Java collection for such a specific task, especially if the API is more intuitive. I also suspect that Java's implementation might actually be a tiny bit faster and produce less garbage (that's a speculation, I didn't measure it).

---

**Original answer**

Java standard collections provide implementations of [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), with `java.util.TreeMap` being one example. The `NavigableMap` provides methods like `floorKey`, `floorEntry`, `ceilingKey` and `ceilingEntry`, which seem to do exactly what you want:

```
import java.util.TreeMap
import java.time.ZonedDateTime

val tm = new TreeMap[ZonedDateTime, Int] // + add entries

def getNearestBeforeTimeStampOffset(timeToCheck: ZonedDateTime)
: Int = tm.floorEntry(timeToCheck).getValue
```

I'm not sure whether Scala's `TreeMap` provides a similar functionality, at least it's not called anything with "ceiling" or "floor" in the name. This [eternally old question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246587/nearest-keys-in-a-sortedmap) also didn't point immediately to the functionality analogous to `NavigableMap`, so maybe it's easier to just use Java's `TreeMap` in this case.

---

To convert scala `Map` to `java.util.TreeMap`, something like this should work:

```
val yourMap: Map[ZonedDateTime, Int] = ???

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val tm = new java.util.TreeMap((yourMap.asJava : java.util.Map[ZonedDateTime, Int]))
```

Comment: is there an easy way to go from scala Map to Java TreeMap?

Comment: @abroy added note on conversion. It definitely should work with `JavaConverters` and maybe some type ascription here and there...

Comment: The ceiling/floor functionality for `TreeMap` is provided by `from` and `to/until` along with `headOption/lastOption`.

Comment: @JoePallas You are right. This whole `to/until`-story seems somehow eerily familiar. Indeed, I've even got a [bounty three years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29731450/2707792) for an answer where I was saying exactly that: `TreeMap` provides `to` that corresponds to `floorKey` and `until` that roughly corresponds to `ceilingKey`. Do you want to post it as a separate answer, or should I update my answer? That probably shouldn't be left as just a comment...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I'd suggest updating your answer.  It's already accepted, so the information may be easier to find the next time someone is looking for it.